# preg_replace exclude "starts with"

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have an array with values that could be formed by one word or multiple ones creating phrases. Each value of this array can also have html tags. I want to match only the ones that don't start with a html tag and replace the word in the array.

I'm looking for "how".

```
"how it's made"
```

becomes

```
"<b>how</b> it's made"
```

while

```
<span style="somethig:value">how it's made</span>
```

should be left untouched.

I tried this

```
$words_result = preg_replace('/^(?!<span).*('.$word.')/', '<b>$1</b>', $words_result);
```

but I always get mixes results, and I don't know to debug it. Plus I've always have problems when dealing with regex expressions :D
For example what is the correspondent $N I should use if the expression is matched?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The dollar numbers represent the brackets you added. $1 is whatever it captured in the first bracket within the regex, $2 is what matched the second bracket etc. In many regex engines $0 will contain the whole match. So in this case you would find your first word stored in $1.

What value does the variable `$word` have? Replacing `$word` with `\w+` and `.*` with `.*?` might work. The question mark is needed to make the period grab as few symbols as possible for the overall term to match (for more detail, have a look at [this Regex reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) and compare `*` with `*?`)

Edit: Based on your comment, your actual problem is that your regex matches everything from the start of the line up to your word and you replace *all* of this with `<b>(word)</b>`. What you could try is putting `.*` into brackets: `(.*)`, so now you will get: `$1` containing everything *up to* the word, and `$2` containing the word itself. Then make the replace string `'$1<b>$2</b>'`.

Comment: so should I change something? mine does match only the ones not starting without <span but the ones matching come out strange for example *"tell me how it's made"* becomes *"<b>how</b> it's made"*. Why does it cut the part before?

Comment: I adjusted the answer a bit :-)

Comment: $word is a precise word that is grabbed from an array inside a foreach

Comment: In your example above it seems `$word` is 'how', so there must be some problem with it. I suggest removing it since you don't need it to determine the first word of a string.

Comment: I need it because if the word is "made" in "how it's made" it won't match and add <b></b> to "made"

Comment: Ohhh, I was under the impression that you wanted to replace the first word of the value. I think I understand what you actually want to do now. I'll change the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something here, but it seems like an easy way to solve this is just to check the first character for an angle bracket:

```
$phrases = array(
    "how it's made",
    "another phrase",
    "<b>Eat the food, Tina!</b>",
    "<i>Fizz</i><u>buzz</u>"
);
foreach ($phrases as $index => $phrase) {
    if ($phrase[0] == '<')
        continue;
    $replacement = preg_replace('/^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/', '<b>$1</b>', $phrase);
    $phrases[$index] = $replacement;
}
```

I'm all for avoiding over-engineering if possible. :)

**EDIT:** Removed the pseudo-code and replaced with real PHP.

Comment: "I can't" do that because both patterns and subjects are values in arrays with random length

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean... As in, the `$phrases` array is an unknown length? Or each `$phrase` is unknown length? Does that matter?

Comment: I mean that the arrays could have different indexes in numbers but it's not relevant :) Anyway why [code]$phrases[0] == "<"[code]? . I need to process every phrase of the array that starts/don't start with html. Plus the pattern '$1' comes from an array of words. I have to parse every word for every value of $phrases. I suppose I need a loop into a loop in the end. I thought preg_replace could avoid all that because it can replace matched patterns and replace the correspondent array key:)

Comment: Your question says that each element in your array is a word or phrase, and you only want to look at the first word of that element. If the first word is enclosed in HTML, the first character of that string will need to be "<". I'm not exactly sure what you're saying?